# Delphi Firemonkey - can't add sub-subclass of TTabItem to TTabControl

Tags: delphi

I can add a TTabItem to a TTabControl, I can add a subclass of a TTabItem to a TabControl, but I can't add a sub-subclass of a TTabItem to a TabControl.

Example Firemonkey application - a form with a TTabControl:

```
type
   TTabItem_subclass = class (TTabItem);
   TTabItem_sub_subclass = class (TTabItem_subclass);

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 procedure add_tab (t: TTabItem);
   begin
     t.Text := t.ClassName;
     t.Parent := TabControl1
  end;
begin
  add_tab (TTabItem.create (TabControl1));   // <-- works
  add_tab (TTabItem_subclass.create (TabControl1));  // <-- works
  add_tab (TTabItem_sub_subclass.create (TabControl1));  // <-- fails
end;
```

When the application is run the TTabItem_sub_subclass doesn't display:

[image]

I've tried this in both XE5 and Tokyo with the same results.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you add a second `TTabItem_subclass` instead of a `TTabItem_sub_subclass`, does *that* fail?

Comment: A second TTabItem_subclass works fine.  I only see the problem with sub-subclass.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem in D10.2.3 and can't immediately see why descending from TTabItem_subclass should cause this problem, but I'm no FMX expert. Update: I think I've found out *why* the sub-sub-class isn't visible, logic in the TTabControl code prevents it from being painted, but I haven't worked out yet how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  I don't think you are missing anything.  If fact, your code **does** successfully add the sub-sub-classed item to the TabControl, it just doesn't get displayed.  I think this problem is caused by a flaw in the way the FMX code derives the style to be used to paint a class which is a sub-sub-class  of TTabItem.  I don't know enough about FMX to idemtify the exact cause of the problem, but I have identified what seems to be a functional work-around.

Please see the code below of a sample project which successfully displays both
TabItem subClass and TabItem sub_subClass tabs.

The reason the code is structured as it is is to make it easy to set a changed-memory breakpoint on
the FResourceLink field of the TabItem (the variable `Item` in the code), while I was
trying to trace how the painting process occurs.

From watching the TabItem.Paint method, it was obvious that the tab would only paint
if its FResourceLink is not nil.  The problem with your original code (and mine)
was that when `Paint` is called on TabItem_subClass, its FResourceLink **has** been assigned
a value whereas for TabItem_sub_subClass it has **not**. Evidently the FResourceLink
is where it picks up the name of the style used to paint the TabItem and if
it can't be found the TabItem doesn't get painted.

I'm afraid that as I'm no expert in FMX I find its code something of a labyrinth
at the best of times and its implementation of styles even more so.  But it
struck me that if I could ensure that a valid style name is returned for
the TabItem GetParentClassStyleLookupName metod, that should suffice.  That's the reason
for the TCustomItem_sub_subclass.GetParentClassStyleLookupName override.  I imagine
an FMX expert might see it as a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a walnut, but there
you go.

Code

```
  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      TabControl1: TTabControl;
      StyleObject1: TStyleObject;  // ignore this
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    private
    public
       Item :  TTabItem;
    end;

  [...]

  implementation

  [...]

  type
     TCustomItem_subclass = class (TTabItem)
     public
       constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
     end;

     TCustomItem_sub_subclass = class (TCustomItem_subclass)
       public
       constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
       function GetParentClassStyleLookupName: string; override;
     end;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

   procedure add_tab (t: TTabItem);
     begin
       t.Text := t.ClassName;
       t.Parent := TabControl1
    end;

   begin

  {$define UseSubSub}
  {$ifdef UseSubSub}
     Item := TCustomItem_sub_subclass.Create(TabControl1);
  {$else}
     Item := TCustomItem_subclass.Create(TabControl1);
  {$endif}

     Item.Text := Item.ClassName;
     Item.Parent := TabControl1;

     Caption := TabControl1.ActiveTab.Text;

     Item := TCustomItem_subclass.Create(TabControl1);

     Item.Text := Item.ClassName;
     Item.Parent := TabControl1;

  end;

  constructor TCustomItem_subclass.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  begin
    inherited;
  end;

  constructor TCustomItem_sub_subclass.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  begin
    inherited;
  end;

  function TCustomItem_sub_subclass.GetParentClassStyleLookupName: string;
  begin
    Result := 'tabitemstyle';
  end;
```

Btw, in doing this I noticed what seems to be a lurking bug in the function
`TStyledControl.GenerateStyleName(const AClassName: string): string` in FMX.Controls.Pas'
If the `AClassName` argument, stripped of a leading `TCustom`, starts with a double-TT,
as in `TCustomTabItem`, the code incorrectly removes the T of TabItem.  I didn't have
time or energy to explore this further but it's why my TabItem sub-classes omit
the `Tab` from their names.

Comment: Thanks - I am totally impressed!  It is a fairly simple workaround that I never would have figured out.  I have submitted this as a bug report to Embarcadero (https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-23539), hopefully they can fix it in a future release.

Comment: I have verified that this fixes the problem in Tokyo 10.2.2 - however it does not fix it in XE5 because GetParentClassStyleLookupName is not in the base class in that version.  None-the-less, this workaround is much appreciated!